# How to show an app helper in the login items in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, authentication

I have created a helper app that will launch the main app on macOS login. To do that I have follow [this tutorial](https://en.atjason.com/Cocoa/SwiftCocoa_Auto%20Launch%20at%20Login.html). All work fine but unfortunately, the helper app is not shown in the Login Items of preferences.

How can I have the helper app to appear in the user's Login Items like iTunesHelper and Dropbox?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Apple documentation there is this information:

> **Adding Login Items**
>
> There are two ways to add a login item: using the **Service Management
> framework**, and using a **shared file list**
>
> Login items installed using the Service Management framework are not
> visible in System Preferences and can only be removed by the
> application that installed them.
>
> Login items installed using a shared file list are visible in System
> Preferences; users have direct control over them. If you use this API,
> your login item can be disabled by the user, so any other application
> that communicates with it it should have reasonable fallback behavior
> in case the login item is disabled.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html

There is a tutorial by Richard Hult [here](http://rhult.github.io/articles/sandboxed-launch-on-login/), it's based on **shared file list**. The tutorial is 2012 (five years ago) so I don't know if it is still suitable. Moreover it's for Objective-C.

Comment: This tutorial works but if your app is an agent (app without window or dock presence), the helper will not launch the main app. One more half-cooked stuff launched by Apple, that brags about the "it just works" stuff.